# jquery tab auto slide

Tags: jquery, tabs, slide

I'm using the following code to create a tab in jquery and when someone clicks it opens that particular tab. So is it possible to modify it such that it can rotate the tabs at the specified interval.

```
    // Tabs
    // When page loads...
    $(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.sidebar-tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab-content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    // On Click Event
    $("ul.sidebar-tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.sidebar-tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
```

The html code for the same is,

```
<ul class="sidebar-tabs">
     <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab2</a></li>
</ul><!-- //sidebar-tabs -->
 <div class="tab-container">
     <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
     <div>
     <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
     <div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

And another example you might get started with http://www.smartnetzone.com/blog_demos/auto_rotating_tabs/

As If you want to modify the existing one you can do this way:

```
jQuery("#tabs").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 3000);
```